# Windows gdipluscolor.h RGB: identifier not found?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am compiling an MFC DLL (MFC dynamically linked). It used to compile flawlessly but now I get the following:

```
Error   2   error C3861: 'RGB': identifier not found    c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\GdiplusColor.h   141
Error   3   error C3861: 'RGB': identifier not found    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlimage.h    1839
Error   4   error C3861: 'RGB': identifier not found    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlimage.h    2048
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: RGB is a preprocessor macro. It's defined in the `Wingdi.h` which should be included by the MFC stdafx includes already. You should check your include directories

Comment: You don't have a `#undef RGB` in your code somewhere, do you?

Answer (score 0):

`RGB` macro is defined in `WinGDI.h` header file as follows:

```
#define RGB(r,g,b)      ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))
```

If you use **GDI+** it is already included in *Gdipluscolor.h (include Gdiplus.h)*
The `Color` class of GDI+ supports it natively:

```
   COLORREF gdiColorRef = RGB(0, 0, 0);   // Set a GDI COLORREF value.
   gdipColor.SetFromCOLORREF(gdiColorRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to redefinition of `RGB` macro by another include file. After finding the include that caused the redefinition, I defined `RGB` again according to Windows API.

```
#define RGB(r,g,b)          ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))
```

In my case, the dependency that redefined `RGB` was `PCL`, so after including all necessary `PCL` headers, I included the above line to define `RGB` as per Windows api.